# How to save radio button input when dynamically loading div tags in a webpage

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications

I tried to build a application for examination.
I am loading the questions dynamically by changing each div tag.
How to save that inputs before submitting entire exam.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more details! Give us specifics, code, what you have tried....

Comment: Where is your code? And look at [localStorage](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/localstorage/) & [$.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: It would be better if you store the result by AJAX, there are many possibilities of losing the data.
If you still want to go your way, you can save the result in a input array type hidden